# Search for a specific error in a string in a row and create a separate column

Tags: regex, oracle, substr, regexp-substr

I have the following text in a column in a table:

```
ERR_COLUMN
Error1|Error2|Error2|Error5|Error6
```

Sample Error:

```
NULL START_TIME|NULL REPAIR_SYMPTOM|NULL PART_ID|NULL PARTS_DC_LOC|NULL 
PART_REPLACE_REASON|INVALID REPAIR SYMPTOM|INVALID PARTS REPLACEMENT REASON
```

My requirement is  to search for an error in a string and separate this into separate columns.  For example:

```
ERR_COLUMN                           Error1 Error2 Error3 Error4 Error5  
Error1|Error2|Error2|Error5|Error6   Error1 Error2 Error3 Error4 Error5
```

Also ,Not sure if this is possible : There is a scenarios where there Will be different errors, Null a, null b,null c..etc. which are part of the Error columns.. I want to find all the errors starting with NULL and decode them to "Error2". THis is in addition to the above.

```
Ex: NULL A, NULL B, NULL C --> 'ERROR2'
```

Thanks,
Kavin

Comment: What are the errors? Some numeric codes? Strings? If every error is different, you could change your patterns to look for specific errors - different for different column...

Comment: @robertus they are all strings! Will add the error description sample.

Comment: *"But the problem is that Error1, sometimes shows up in the Error2 column"* -  could you tell us with an example when this is happening?

Comment: @KaushikNayak i am just searching using '|' , so based on different rows, the errors chnage...as i explained earlier, some rows would have only Error1|Error2 some will have all the errors, based on this the placement of the Error will change will splitting into seperate columns. I want the Error1 to always show up in Error1 column and so on..

Comment: On what basis do you decide something should belong to Error1 and not Error2 or vice versa?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Based on the string itself "Error1". If i search for error1, and its found, create a new column with same name.

Comment: Note that it is always appropriate to ask one question at a time in StackOverflow. You may check my answer for the first part and accept if it works. The second part, though achievable - at this point I expect some effort from you to work on a little bit and ask a separate question when you face difficulty.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Thanks a ton. The solution provided by you works great and is exactly what i was looking for. For the second part, will try and get back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  `'(^|\|)(Errorpattern)($|\|)'` by capturing the error pattern in the second match group `()`

`(^|\|)` - matches a start of string or pipe
`($|\|)` - matches end of string or pipe

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/059e5/14)

**Query**:

```
SELECT 
ERR_COLUMN,
 regexp_substr(ERR_COLUMN,'(^|\|)(Error1)($|\|)',1,1,NULL,2) as "Error1"
,regexp_substr(ERR_COLUMN,'(^|\|)(Error2)($|\|)',1,1,NULL,2) as "Error2"
,regexp_substr(ERR_COLUMN,'(^|\|)(Error3)($|\|)',1,1,NULL,2) as "Error3"
,regexp_substr(ERR_COLUMN,'(^|\|)(Error4)($|\|)',1,1,NULL,2) as "Error4"
,regexp_substr(ERR_COLUMN,'(^|\|)(Error5)($|\|)',1,1,NULL,2) as "Error5"
FROM t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/059e5/14/0)**:

```
|                         ERR_COLUMN | Error1 | Error2 | Error3 | Error4 | Error5 |
|------------------------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| Error1|Error2|Error2|Error5|Error6 | Error1 | Error2 | (null) | (null) | Error5 |
|              Error3|Error4|Error5| | (null) | (null) | Error3 | Error4 | Error5 |
|              Error1|Error2|Error6| | Error1 | Error2 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.